# redirecting to an area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can not redirect to an area, a message appears "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values". No route matches the supplied values.

**Startup.cs**

I created these routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("areaRoute","area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

**LoginController.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GravarCadastro(CadastroModel novoUsuario)
{
    RedirectToActionResult redirecionar;
    switch (novoUsuario.perfil)
    {
        case 1:
            //not Working
            redirecionar = RedirectToAction("Index", "Paciente");                  
            break;
        case 2:
            //not Working
            redirecionar = RedirectToAction("Index", "medico");
            break;
        case 3:
            //not Working
            redirecionar = RedirectToAction("Index", "farmacia");
            break;
        case 4:
            //not Working
            redirecionar = RedirectToAction("Index", "laboratorio");
            break;

        default:
           //not Working
            redirecionar = RedirectToAction("Index", "paciente");
            break;
    }

    return redirecionar;
}
```

**PacienteController.cs**

I'm using these attributes

```
[AllowAnonymous] 
[Area("Paciente")]
[Route("Paciente")]
public class PacienteController : Controller
{
    //[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

[strutured in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egov9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area needs to be specified but there is no overload of RedirectToAction that takes it as a direct parameter. So you need to do:

```
redirecionar = RedirectToAction("Index", "Paciente", new { area = "Paciente" });
```

Side note: naming a Controller and an Area the same is not advisable. Consider the plural of Paciente (Pacientas ?) for the Area.

Comment: I've tried this, the project is in Portuguese, so it's "Paciente"

Comment: Well... be creative.

Comment: I tried without the attributes in the controller and it did not work